# Unable to create row for each transaction and sort in ascending order in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

I have a json data that looks like below:

```
{
"hits":{
"runid2":{
"RequestId":"SR0273",
"usecasedetails":[
{
"Responsetime":{
"U1_test_AddProduct_10_Menu":"348",
"U1_test_05_ClickAerin":"590",
"U1_test_AddProduct_06_SelectProduct":"1394",
"U1_test_AddProduct_08_OpenBasket":"3620"
},
"referenceid":17
},
{
"Responsetime":{
"App-Launch":"2047"
},
"referenceid":18
}
],
"DeviceName":"[Nexus 6P2]"
},
"runid1":{
"RequestId":"SR0271",
"usecasedetails":[
{
"Responsetime":{
"U1_test_AddProduct_10_Menu":"3480",
"U1_test_05_ClickAerin":"5900",
"U1_test_AddProduct_06_SelectProduct":"139",
"U1_test_AddProduct_08_OpenBasket":"362"
},
"referenceid":17
},
{
"Responsetime":{
"App-Launch":"2047"
},
"referenceid":18
}
],
"DeviceName":"[Nexus 6P1]"
}
}
}
```

i used below code to parse the json data:

```
$.getJSON("comparison.json", function(json) {

         var Hits= json.hits;
        var runIdArr =[];
          var runIdcount = Object.keys(Hits).length;


          var count = Object.keys(Hits).length;
  //alert("count = "+ count);
  var usecaseCount =Hits.runid1.usecasedetails.length;

var devicename,usecasedetails,responsetime,tablerow;




  for(var i = 0; i<usecaseCount ;i++)
  {

               var tableHeadingrow = document.createElement('tr');
      var tablerow = document.createElement('tr');
    var tablerow1= document.createElement('tr');
    var tablerow2= document.createElement('tr');
    var tablerowPara= document.createElement('tr');
    var tablerow3= document.createElement('tr');


    var tableHeadingheader=document.createElement('th');
    var tableheader=document.createElement('th');
    var tableheader1=document.createElement('th');
    var tableheader2=document.createElement('th');
    var tableheaderPara=document.createElement('th');



    tableHeadingheader.style.textAlign="center";
    tableheader.style.textAlign="center";

    var usecasedetails =  Hits.runid1.usecasedetails ;

        var usecasename = usecasedetails[i].usecasename;

   tableHeadingheader.setAttribute("style","font-weight: bold;color:#3c9adc");
    tableHeadingheader.innerHTML=usecasename+" ResponseTime Summary";
    tableheader.innerHTML="Report#";
    tableheader1.innerHTML="DeviceName";
    tableheader2.innerHTML="UseCase";
    tableheaderPara.innerHTML="Transaction Name";



    if(i==0)
    {
      tablerow.appendChild(tableheader);
      tablerow1.appendChild(tableheader1);
    }
    tableHeadingrow.appendChild(tableHeadingheader);
      tablerow2.appendChild(tableheader2);
    tablerowPara.appendChild(tableheaderPara);






    for(var j=1; j<=count; j++)
          {

        var RequestId = Hits["runid"+j].RequestId;

         var devicename = Hits["runid"+j].DeviceName;

        var usecasedetails =  Hits["runid"+j].usecasedetails ;

        var usecasename = usecasedetails[i].usecasename;

          var Responsetime=(usecasedetails[i].Responsetime);
        var resTimeLength = Object.keys(Responsetime).length;




          Object.keys(Responsetime).forEach(function(key)
          {
            if(j==1)
            {


              var tableheader3=document.createElement('tr');
              tableheader3.innerHTML=key;
            //alert("hi saket"+key);

              tablerow3.appendChild(tableheader3);
            }



          });



        var k=1;
        var ss = document.createElement('td');
        Object.keys(Responsetime).forEach(function(key)
          {

      //    alert("the value of k is "+ k)

          value = Responsetime[key];

          var tablecolum3=document.createElement('tr');  

          if(value<5000)
                {
               // document.getElementById('launchpanel2').className+= 'panel panel-green';
               tablecolum3.innerHTML=value;

                }
                else if((value>5000)&&(value<=6000))
                {
                  tablecolum3.setAttribute("style","color:#ffbf00;font-weight:bold");
                 tablecolum3.innerHTML=value;

            }
                else if(value>6000)
                {

                tablecolum3.setAttribute("style","color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold");
                 tablecolum3.innerHTML=value;
                }




      //    alert("hi saket 2nd time");
          ss.appendChild(tablecolum3);  
      //    tablerow3.appendChild(saket);
          k++;
        });
        tablerow3.appendChild(ss);

        var tableHeader=document.createElement('th');
        var tableHeader1=document.createElement('th');
        var tableSubHeader=document.createElement('th');


        tableHeader.innerHTML=RequestId;
            tableHeader1.innerHTML=devicename;
          tableSubHeader.innerHTML=usecasename;   


        if(i==0)
        {
          tablerow.appendChild(tableHeader);
          tablerow1.appendChild(tableHeader1);
        }
        tablerow2.appendChild(tableSubHeader);


      }

      document.getElementById("responseTableoady").appendChild(tableHeadingrow);
      document.getElementById("responseTableoady").appendChild(tablerow);
      document.getElementById("responseTableoady").appendChild(tablerow1);
  //    document.getElementById("responseTableoady").appendChild(tablerow2);
      document.getElementById("responseTableoady").appendChild(tablerowPara);
      document.getElementById("responseTableoady").appendChild(tablerow3);

           }         

        });
```

All my transaction names and values are getting appended to the same row. Like below image:

[image]

Ultimately, i would like to create a unique row for each transaction and its corresponding responsetime and sort the transaction name in ascending order.I may be doing  this wrong, so if there is an easier way to accomplish that end goal, I am open to ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you appending header ``th`` every time?

Comment: No i dont. th will get appended only when i=0